# Google Firebase Authentication Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase

Im attempting to configure the new google firebase authentication in my app.

I am receiving `cannot resolve 'addOnCOmpleteListener'` when running the following within the `OnClickListener` for the button.

If i move the *firebase* call out of the buttons `onClickListener` then the error goes,

I cant quite understand why the method is not accessible from within the button call

Any Help would be appreciated

```
package com.example.alex.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;


public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    Button buttonLogin;
    EditText textEmail;
    EditText textPassword;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        buttonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
        textEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
        textPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d("LOG_Login", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d("LOG_Login", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
                // ...
            }
        };




        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on clic

                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(textEmail.getText().toString(),textPassword.getText().toString())
                        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                Log.d("LOG_Login", "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Log.w("LOG_Login", "signInWithEmail", task.getException());
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }

                                // ...
                            }
                        });
            }
        });

    }
}
```

i am using Android Studio 2.2

I have created a project within Firebase

I have connected my app to this within the GUI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If i move the firebase call out of the buttons onClickListener then the error goes,
>
> I cant quite understand why the method is not accessible from within the button call

Because `this` is the click listener when you have it inside the anonymous class.

The method requires an Activity as the first parameter to the `addOnCompleteListener` and not an OnClickListener.

```
.addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, ...
```

Comment: thanks for the help, worked a treat I had tried getApplicationContext() but this hadn't worked

Comment: Yeah, not sure why it requires an Activity, I had to go look at the documentation